# python print all function calls to know the script flow

Tags: python, stack-trace

How can I print every function/method call ?
I have tried to use : `python -m trace --trace` but it prints also the function inner code... I just want functions names that were called.
using traceback in code prints the last function called before calling the command itself, and the code contains many classes...

Answer (score 8):

You may find `-l` useful.

main.py:

```
def foo():
    pass

def bar():
    pass

foo()
bar()
```

Doing

```
$ python -m trace -l main.py
```

outputs

```
functions called:
filename: C:\Python34\lib\trace.py, modulename: trace, funcname: _unsettrace
filename: main.py, modulename: main, funcname: <module>
filename: main.py, modulename: main, funcname: bar
filename: main.py, modulename: main, funcname: foo
```

Depending on the number of functions you have, you may find a decorator more suitable:

```
def print_deco(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        print(func.__name__)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return inner

@print_deco
def foo():
    pass

@print_deco
def bar():
    pass

foo()
bar()

# foo
# bar
```

Comment: `python -m trace -l main.py`prints by alphabet order and not the call order.
adding decorator is not an options... too many functions and classes and I didn't write the code. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

here is the code with name `player.py`.

```
# player.py
def foo():
    pass
def bar():
    foo()
def car():
    bar()
    pass
car()
```

executed the command from the terminal like `$python -m trace -T player.py` and it gives me the following output. you can also use for `--trackcalls` instead of `-T` for the same output. And that command Display the calling relationships exposed by running the program.

```
calling relationships:

*** /usr/lib/python2.7/trace.py ***
    trace.Trace.runctx -> trace._unsettrace
  --> player.py
    trace.Trace.runctx -> player.<module>

*** player.py ***
    player.<module> -> player.car
    player.bar -> player.foo
    player.car -> player.bar
```

Hope this will help.

**Update 1:**

the above command display the function's relationship.

For tracing the function we can use `traceback` module. In this module `traceback.print_stack()` print the function depending on the execution. But we have to keep in mind that in which method we write the `traceback.print_stack()` it will only print the trace of that function. I will give you an example.

```
import traceback
def foo():
    car()
    pass
def bar():
    foo()
def car():
    traceback.print_stack()
    pass
bar()
```

and if we run this we can see the following output.

```
File "D:/python_practice36/player.py", line 10, in <module>
bar()
File "D:/python_practice36/player.py", line 6, in bar
foo()
File "D:/python_practice36/player.py", line 3, in foo
car()
File "D:/python_practice36/player.py", line 8, in car
traceback.print_stack()
```

if we call the `traceback.print_stack()` in `foo()` then we can see the traceback upto `foo`.

```
import traceback
def foo():
    car()
    traceback.print_stack()
    pass
def bar():
    foo()
def car():
    pass
bar()
```

and the output is

```
File "D:/python_practice36/player.py", line 10, in <module>
bar()
File "D:/python_practice36/player.py", line 7, in bar
foo()
File "D:/python_practice36/player.py", line 4, in foo
traceback.print_stack()
```