# print trace of origins of each call to a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

What specific syntax needs to be added to the code below in order to print out the full trace of the chain of function calls that result in each time that `four.myFunction()` gets called in the code sameple below?

```
one.py
  import two
  import three
  two.twoFunction()
  three.threeFunction()

two.py
  import four
  def twoFunction():
    four.myFunction()

three.py
  import four
  def threeFunction():
    four.myFunction()

four.py
  def myFunction():
    print("trace of which functions called me, back to original.")
```

This is important because we have functions that seem to be run more times than the code looks like the functions should be run.

If we can isolate the chain of calling scripts/functions for each call to `four.myFunction()`, we will be able to more closely diagnose what might be going on.

We are using Python 3.

Comment: You can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44996393/python-print-all-function-calls-to-know-the-script-flow) question.

Comment: You can use [`traceback.print_stack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.print_stack).

Comment: @0x5453 What syntax should be used to print the traceback to a file located at `pathAndFileName`?  When we try `traceback.print_stack(file=pathAndFileName)`, we get `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'`.

Comment: @CodeMed You have to [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) the file and pass the handle.  `with open(pathAndFileName, 'w') as f: traceback.print_stack(file=f)`

Answer (score 0):

With each of your functions, you can require an input like `def ...(past_calls):`and add the current function to it when calling another.

i.e.

```
def NthFunction(past_calls):
    # Call next function, adding current to the trace.
    NextFunction(past_calls + [n])
```

And when you are printing your results, you can use the information given as the parameter (you can also add more details if need be).